# gridview won't populate with custom connection string and custom datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i've set up an userdefined connection string and now trying to populate a gridview using that,breakpoint shows connection string's fine..also no error,but surprisingly datatable is n't receiving any value..although data exists...what have i done wrong??

**Default3.Aspx:**

```
<td colspan="2" align="center">
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">       
  </asp:GridView>     
</td>
```

**Default3.Aspx.Cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string con = OracleDatabase.connection();
    String SelectCommand = "select * from EMP";

    OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(SelectCommand, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    /* 
    OracleDatabase.gridpopulate(SelectCommand, GridView1);
    GridView1.DataSource = OracleDatabase.gridpopulate(SelectCommand);
    GridView1.DataBind();
    */ 
    //i tried doing this by writting a function At class file also
}
```

**Class file:**

```
public static string connection()
{
    oradb = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]
           .ConnectionString;
    string str = "Data Source="+db+";User ID="+userid+";Password="+password+";";
    oradb = String.Concat(oradb, str);        
    con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
    con.Open();
    return oradb;
}

/*(function for gridpopulate)
public static void gridpopulate(string SelectCommand,GridView grid1)
{
    string con =(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]
                 .ConnectionString);
    con = String.Concat(con, str);
    adp = new OracleDataAdapter(SelectCommand,con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    grid1.DataSource = dt;
    grid1.DataBind();
    //return dt;         
 }
*/
```

Comment: Why did you do autogeneratecolumns=false? You either need to set that to true or add some markup defining your columns.

Comment: you sure the `oradb = String.Concat(oradb, str);` results into correct  connection string???

Comment: yes...the connection string's fine...

Answer (score 1):

Try as per below, instead of returning connection string from function return Oracle Connection object and pass the same to Adapter.

```
OracleConnection con = OracleDatabase.connection();

public static OracleConnection connection()
{
 oradb =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 string str = "Data Source="+db+";User ID="+userid+";Password="+password+";";
 oradb = String.Concat(oradb, str);        
 con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
 con.Open();
 return con;
}
```

Comment: sorry to reply that the datatable still isn't receiving any data...y'r logic seems brilliant...but for some unknown reason it doesn't populate the grid...is it running @ y'r end??

Comment: Have you set AutoGenerateColumns = True ?? Please check